# mysql partitions by key not evenly distributed

Tags: mysql, partition

I have a problem with a MySQL table with over 30 MM records.

It was very slow on queries made by the key so I decided to use partitions.
after that, it became way faster, but today I was checking the partitions and something is wrong.

I did 16 partitions by key, the key was a uniqid() so they were unique but kind of sequential.

When I checked how many records each partition has, it was like

> partition 0 - 3.5 MM
>   partition 1 - 0
>   partition 2 - 3.2 MM
>   partition 3 - 0
>   partition 4 - 8.5 MM
>   partition 5 - 0
>   partition 6 - 2.9 MM
>   partition 7 - 0
>   and so on

I don't care if one partition has two or three times more than others, but I don't understand why the 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 partitions have zero records. so 8 out of 16 partitions are empty.

I thought it could be due to the sequential numbers so I changed the key to a md5 unique value, so every data starts with random data, but the pattern is the same, 8 partitions handle all the data, the other 8 are completely empty.

Why is this happening and what could I do to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: What was the DDL to create the partitions?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE t1 PARTITION BY KEY(id) PARTITIONS 16;`
my table is InnoDB

Comment: Yeah I was hoping it was something with setup; but it doesn't appear so. 
 Maybe rebuilding the partitions would help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-maintenance.html as it indicates it may help with fragmentation.